# VBA Macro to compare columns in Excel and display the differences in a third column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a macro button to compare column A and column B in Excel, with any differences being listed in column C.

- I want all values in A that are not in B to display in C
- I want all values in B that are not in A to also display in C.
- I want to be able to do this regardless of what data is put into A or B.

Comment: Please show an example. Do you mean that either A can be empty or B? Otherwise if A = 7 and B = 8, what do you want in C? B.t.w. Do you need VBA for this as this to mee seems like a formula, no need for VBA.

Comment: I want a user to be able paste in 2 columns of data to compare and then hit a button to compare the two columns. As an example, if A1 = 1, A2 = 3, B1 =2, and B2 = 3, I want C to display the values that are not in both columns, which are 1 and 2 in this example.

Comment: Please check the changes that I made to your question and confirm. B.t.w. the edits that I made are awaiting review, so it may take some time before they are visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a toolbar with a button on it that runs Sub SelectionCompare. Highlight the 2 columns that have data and click the button. Blam!

You can tweak this code to get better handling for blanks, row headings, duplicates, detection of improper starting conditions (like no selection or an improperly sized selection), or detection/prevention of overwriting data in the output column.

```
Function ClipRange(Value As Excel.Range) As Excel.Range
   Set ClipRange = Application.Intersect(Value, Value.Parent.UsedRange)
End Function

Function RangeToDict(Value As Excel.Range) As Object
   Dim Cell As Excel.Range
   Set RangeToDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   For Each Cell In Value
      If Not RangeToDict.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
         RangeToDict.Add Cell.Value, 1
      End If
   Next
End Function

Sub ColumnCompare(Column1 As Excel.Range, Column2 As Excel.Range, OutputColumn As Excel.Range)
   Dim Dict1 As Object
   Dim Dict2 As Object
   Dim Cell As Excel.Range
   Dim Key As Variant
   Set Dict1 = RangeToDict(ClipRange(Column1))
   Set Dict2 = RangeToDict(ClipRange(Column2))
   Set Cell = OutputColumn.Cells(1, 1)
   For Each Key In Dict1
      If Not Dict2.Exists(Key) Then
         Cell.Value = Key
         Set Cell = Cell.Offset(1, 0)
      End If
   Next
   For Each Key In Dict2
      If Not Dict1.Exists(Key) Then
         Cell.Value = Key
         Set Cell = Cell.Offset(1, 0)
      End If
   Next
End Sub

Sub SelectionCompare()
   ColumnCompare Selection.Columns(1), Selection.Columns(2), Selection.Columns(2).Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for trying to be helpful!

Comment: No problem at all! Your edit was flagged for review is all. Perhaps it is a mistake to make any comments--my apologies.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! What exactly is going on in all that code?

Comment: Clip the columns to just the used rows of the workbook. Put all distinct values of each column in a dictionary. Compare each dictionary to the other and put non-matches into the next column.